# Can't map the JSON object from Couchbase to DTO entity using Spring Data Couchbase

Tags: java, spring, couchbase, spring-data-couchbase

I have created some Data Model Objects to insert and read from Couchbase. It has simple types and 2 fields are other DTO objects.

```
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@Document
public class Customer {

    @Id
    private int id;

    private String fullName;

    private String phoneNumber;

    private String address;

    private Date registrationDate;

    private boolean isBusiness;

    private String status;

    private Tariff currentTariff;

    private BillingAccount billingAccount;
}
```

So, I made and endpoint with logic for creating 10 000 of random Customer Objects, then it does repository.saveAll(customers);

I can see this data added in Couchbase UI

But then **I want to get all this Customer Objects from Couchbase**. Here's my code

```
    @GetMapping("/findAllCustomers")
    public Iterable<Customer> getAll() {
        return repository.findAll();
    }
```

Very simple, no custom conversion, no other complicated stuff. The type I'm expecting is exactly the type that I was generating and saving this data with.

**I get the following error :**

> Failed to instantiate com.bachelor.boostr.model.Customer using
>   constructor public com.bachelor.boostr.model.Customer
>
> Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be
>   cast to java.lang.Integer\r\n\tat
>   com.bachelor.boostr.model.Customer_Instantiator_z47nsm.newInstance(Unknown
>   Source)\r\n\tat
>   org.springframework.data.convert.ClassGeneratingEntityInstantiator$EntityInstantiatorAdapter.createInstance(ClassGeneratingEntityInstantiator.java:226)\r\n\t...

Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I removed @AllArgsConstructor Lombok Annotation, and created constructor without the Id field

```
@Data
@Document
public class Customer {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationStrategy.UNIQUE)
    private String id;

    private String fullName;

    private String phoneNumber;

    private String address;

    private Date registrationDate;

    private boolean isBusiness;

    private String status;

    private Tariff currentTariff;

    private BillingAccount billingAccount;

    public Customer(String fullName, String phoneNumber, String address, Date registrationDate, boolean isBusiness, String status, Tariff currentTariff, BillingAccount billingAccount) {
        this.fullName = fullName;
        this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
        this.address = address;
        this.registrationDate = registrationDate;
        this.isBusiness = isBusiness;
        this.status = status;
        this.currentTariff = currentTariff;
        this.billingAccount = billingAccount;
    }
}
```

After that it worked just fine. Both read and write operations.